# Zend_Session and charset compatibility issue after browser restarting

Tags: php, zend-framework, character-encoding, iso-8859-1, zend-session

I am facing a charset/session issue.

Context : I developed a web site using [Zend](http://framework.zend.com/). I must use the ISO-8859-1 charset. During the user utilization, some data are stored into sessions variables ([Zend_session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html)) and everything is fine.

But, once the user close and restart the browser after few seconds, the user sessions variables have been converted into UTF-8 charset and all accents are not displayed correctly!

So, my questions are:
- Is it possible to specify the [Zend_Session](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.session.basic_usage.html) charset to use when the data are stored on the server side?
- Is it possible to force the session clean-up when the user close its browser?

Thanks you in advance!

Comment: Are you storing sessions in the database or on the file system?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The sessions are managed by Zend, therefore I think that the data are stored on the file system. In fact, I am thinking that the data are set correctly the first time because they are stocked into the RAM. When the browser closes its connection with the server, the session data are saved into the file system in the UTF-8 charset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no issue...

I migrated from charset UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 and I had an old version of my web site still opened in my browser.

So, at the browser launching, both versions of my web site were loading at the same time and pushed data into php session variables.

My mistake